# Finding a vector many times

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a vector matrix of profits say

```
prof= {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}};
```

I have a "terminal value vector" as

```
vt={1,2,3,4,5};
```

and a constant

```
npva=2;
```

Now the problem is to find `vt` at each preceding step of $v(t - 1), v(t - 2)...v(0)$ taking the Maximum of (the average of the `vt` + profits at each time `t`, `npva`) and then putting the resulting `max` as the `vt` of the following step.

So given the average of `vt=3` (a scalar), I add `prof[[5]]` so that I get `{8,8,8,8,8}` and then take the Max of EACH ELEMENT OF THIS VECTOR compared to `npva`. This gives $v(t-1)=\{8,8,8,8,8\}$. So for the next step, I take the average of $v(t-1)$, but add `prof[[4]]`, and then taking the Max compared with `npva`, I get the vector $v(t-2)$ and so on..

I tried to use `For` first but it doesn't work.  I think `FoldList` can be used, but I do not know how to pull in each row from another matrix when the process is repeated. Above all, how can you incorporate the Max that I want in the command? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code you have developed for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your `vt` and `prof` lists together.

```
 list = {vt, prof}
```

The function `findVt` gives the next combined list of `vt` and `prof`. Form `prof` it drops the last element.

```
findVt[comList_] := 
Module[{npva = 2, profList, profLen, mean, vtList, list1, list2},
vtList = First@comList;
profList = Last@comList;
profLen = Length[profList];
mean = Mean[vtList];
list1 = Last@profList + mean;
list2 = Max[#, npva] & /@ list1;
profList = Drop[profList, {profLen}];
{list2, profList}
]
```

Lets check the function

```
 findVt[list]

 (*{{8, 8, 8, 8, 8}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4,4}}}*)
```

So it gives the expected result. Now we can use `NestWhileList` with the condition on the length of the `prof` list.

```
 res = NestWhileList[findVt, list, Length[#[[2]]] >= 1 &];
```

`res` will store the combined list including the `prof` list at each iteration.
Just the `vt` results are as follows.

```
 res[[All, 1]]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {8, 8, 8, 8, 8}, {12, 12, 12, 12, 12}, {15, 15, 15, 15, 15}, {17, 17, 17, 17, 17}, {18, 18, 18, 18, 18}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have tried the code with success. Sincerely.